# find command excluding subdirectory

Tags: bash, loops, command

Sorry, but the other questions did not help me :/
I want to loop over a directory to apply a program over certain files.
The problem is that it also includes subdirectories.
Whats wrong with my code?:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find $path/* \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.out" \) -prune -maxdepth 1 -type f `;
do
    
    program "$file" -outdir=$outdir;
    
done
```

Comment: The very *purpose* of `find` is to traverse subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the output of `find` as a list in a `for` loop. It won't work when a filename contains a whitespace character, and anyway it is  superfluous to call an external command for this job. Use globs instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for file in "$path"/*.txt "$path"/*.out; do
   program "$file" -outdir="$outdir"
done
```

Notes:

- The `nullglob` option, when it is enabled, causes the pattern to be removed from the list when no files matching the pattern were found. The pattern would be left unchanged otherwise.
- The `"$path"/*.txt "$path"/*.out` can be reduced to `"$path"/{*.txt,*.out}`.
- The patterns above won't match the filenames beginning with a dot (`.`), but it is possible to remedy this, if desired.
- The files matching the pattern don't have to be regular files. It might be a good idea to check this by `[[ -f "$file" ]] || continue`, at the top of the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I was obviously too blind! :D
The easiest solutions are the best.